# AMQP-CPP RabbitMQ Build Integrating to CPP Project

Tags: c++, amqp

Hi I currently try to integrate RabbitMQ via AMQPCPP into my VisualStudio Project. I am restricted to use a Windows PC which is a pain in the ass for the installation.
I think I was able to build the Project using CMAKE[image: Build] But I received some Error doing it [image: Error CMAKE GUI]. Now I am trying to include the build into the VS2017 Project. In the Readme https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP this is done using

```
#include <amqpcpp.h>
```

But this header is not found in my build. I am not used to CPP so I hope I havent done some rudimental error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Steps to build AMQP-CPP using CMake in Windows - Visual Studio 2017**

Open command prompt and switch to AMQP-CPP git/source path.

### 1) **>mkdir build**

### 2) **>cd build**

### 3) **>cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..\**

```
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.15063.0 to target Windows 6.1.7601.
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.10.25019.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.10.25019.0
    -- Check for working C compiler: E:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working C compiler: E:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x64/cl.exe -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x64/cl.exe -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: D:/Projects/AMQP-CPP/build
```

### 4) **>cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config RELEASE --clean-first -- /m**

Build succeeded.

```
   "D:\Projects\AMQP-CPP\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->       "D:\Projects\AMQP-CPP\build\amqpcpp.vcxproj" (default target) (3)        ->       (ClCompile target) ->
     D:\Projects\AMQP-CPP\src\deferredreceiver.cpp(48): warning C424
   4: 'argument': conversion from 'uint64_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss o
   f data [D:\Projects\AMQP-CPP\build\amqpcpp.vcxproj]

1 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:44.16

### How to include amqpcpp in your project

Edit your project CMakeLists.txt file for adding amqpcpp include path and library path for linking.

```
    include_directories(../include)
    link_directories(../build/bin/Release)
```

Include and link directory path may differ based on actual location in your machine.